# simple c++, opengl game engine for linux?

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, game-engine

I was wondering if anyone knew of a simple opengl game engine for linux where the source is available to read.

I basically want to read the source to get a better idea of how things are put together without worrying about the code being cross platform or having fancy particle effects or anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be interested in [Irrlicht](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrlicht_Engine)

Comment: I've used Irrlicht and Ogre a little and I much prefer Irrlicht.  It's much simpler and has many fewer dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [DevMaster](http://www.devmaster.net/), a website with a lot of information about game programming and a [3D Engines Database](http://www.devmaster.net/engines/).

Answer (score 0):

[You might want to check Ogre](http://www.ogre3d.org/)

Answer (score -1):

[SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/opengl/index.php) supports OpenGL, is open source, and you can port your game to Windows if you want. I've used it to write a Tetris program. It supports C and C++.

Answer (score -1):

A simple engine for beginners, written in C++, contains samples to start with and sample game project to study:
[D'Enfent Engine](http://sourceforge.net/projects/denfent-engine/)

Comment: Fixed link to what I expect is the right page.